# ¿Cómo hacer el envío de mensajes por puertos COM?

Tags: android, windows10, puertos

Estoy intentando enviar mensajes a través del móvil conectado a la PC, esto lo intento hacer con **comandos AT** (sólo porque no he encontrado otra solución), bueno para esto conecto el móvil en modo de módem, y para realizar la conección con el mismo debería aparecer el **puerto COM** en el administrador de dispositivo, pero no aparece y no encuentro la solución. ¿Se entiende?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el sistema operativo de tu móvil y de tu PC?

Comment: android 5.1 y windows 10

Comment: Te aparece el dispositivo marcado como amarillo en el administrador de dispositivos?

Comment: en modo de modem no aparece, eh probado con otros dispositivos que si aparecen pero los comandos at no funcionan, devuelven error 500